# Thread Pool task list update issue

Tags: java, multithreading, java-8, threadpool

I am trying to design a thread pool at my end in java. As per my design I am using a java's Linkedlist  DS inside a main runner thread class to hold on to all the submitted tasks. This task list is getting updated from the main class wherein the main class is adding a tasks to the task list. Inside my main runner thread I am running a while loop and constantly checking for whether the LinkedList is not empty , and if it contains a task then i am retrieving the task and executing it.

The problem here is that I have added a task from my main method in to the task list and I can see the size of this task list to be 1 from main method but inside the runner thread when i print the size of task list object , it shows it as 0.

Need help figuring out what exactly is happening here.

```
public class ReusableThread<T> extends Thread{
    private volatile Queue<Work<T>> tasks = new LinkedList<Work<T>>();
    private Work<T> currentWork;

    private class Work<T>{
        Result<T> result;
        Taskable<T> task;

        public Work(Result<T> result, Taskable<T> task) {
            this.result = result;
            this.task = task;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true){
            //System.out.println("ReusableThread.run()");
            System.out.println("Inside thread : " + getTasks().size()); //This print 0
            if(!tasks.isEmpty()){      
               currentWork = getWork();
               T value = currentWork.task.run();

               //currentWork.result.setValue(currentWork.task.run());
            }
            //currentWork.result.setComplete(true);
        }
    }

    public Work<T> getWork() {
        return tasks.remove();
    }

    public Queue<Work<T>> getTasks() {
        return tasks;
    }

    public Result<T> submit(Taskable<T> task) {
        Result<T> result = new Result<T>();
        this.tasks.add(new Work<T>(result, task));
        return result;
    }
}
```

The main thread is as below :

```
public void test() throws InterruptedException {
    int count = 0;  
    ReusableThread<Integer> rt = new ReusableThread();
    rt.start();

    Thread.sleep(1000);

        System.out.println("Thread-"+ count +" starting");
        Result<Integer> result = rt.submit(JavaUtils::task);
        System.out.println("In main : " + rt.getTasks().size()); //This prints 1
}
```

Comment: Rewrite your title to summarize your specific technical issue versus all the other Questions about thread pool issues.

Comment: Updated the title as per the issue.

Comment: Well, with a forever loop without any sleep between each poll, I highly suspect that you have missed that line of size = 1 message.  Can you create a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ?

Comment: How does that cause an issue ?

Comment: @BasilBourque I think the question has been sufficiently asked and does not need a further explanation. Could you please let me know your issue with this ?

Comment: @rootExplorr My Comment is moot now that the Answer has been closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is a thread-safety problem.  Specifically:

1. a `LinkedList` is not thread-safe, and
2. you are using the `LinkedList` object in `rt.getTasks().size()` without any synchronization.

This is sufficient to cause `size()` to return a stale value under some circumstances.

---

If you are going to rely on the semantics of `volatile` you need to do a proper analysis of the *happens-before* relationships for each write / read sequence that matters to thread safety.  It is tricky.

My advice would be:

1. Don't use `volatile`.  Use `synchronized` and/or an existing thread-safe data structure instead ... if you *need* to reinvent the wheel.
2. Don't reinvent the wheel.  You could replace your thread pool with a single call `Executors.singleThreadExecutor`; see [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor()).

Comment: Agreed , but only in some circumstances and here I am continuously looping to find whether List is empty or not , so eventually the correct value should appear

Comment: *"so eventually the correct value should appear"* - Not necessarily.  It is only guaranteed that the correct value will appear if there is a *happens-before* relationship from the write to the read.

Comment: Can you enlighten me with some links to read further on this ?

Comment: 1) Google is a good way to find links.  2) https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.  or buy a copy of Goetz et al "Java Concurrency in Practice"

Comment: Very well could i have used the Java Executor service but just wanted to write the thread pool on my own :)

Comment: In that case, you need to do a lot of reading.  It is not a simple matter to implement a correct (thread-safe) data structure from the ground up.  If you want to learn, I recommend that you buy and read Goetz.

Comment: Yes correct , but whats the fun in doing easy things and especially when we have places like SOF and helping people like you challenges are not an issue :)

Answer (score 1):

You're missing synchronize 'tasks', so two thread (main and ReusableThread) random access to `tasks`, so you will not know what happen, I've modified your code:

```java
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;

class Result<T> {
}

interface Taskable<T> {

    T run();

}

class JavaUtils {

    public static Integer task() {
        return 1;
    }

}

public class ReusableThread<T> extends Thread{
    private volatile Queue<Work<T>> tasks = new LinkedList<Work<T>>();
    private Work<T> currentWork;

    private class Work<T>{
        Result<T> result;
        Taskable<T> task;

        public Work(Result<T> result, Taskable<T> task) {
            this.result = result;
            this.task = task;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true){
            //System.out.println("ReusableThread.run()");
            synchronized (tasks) {
                if (!tasks.isEmpty()) {
                    System.out.println("Inside thread : " + tasks.size()); //This print 0
                    currentWork = tasks.remove();
                    T value = currentWork.task.run();

                    //currentWork.result.setValue(currentWork.task.run());
                }
            }
            //currentWork.result.setComplete(true);
        }
    }

    public Work<T> getWork() {
        synchronized (tasks) {
            return tasks.remove();
        }
    }

    public Queue<Work<T>> getTasks() {
        synchronized (tasks) {
            return tasks;
        }
    }

    public int getTaskSize() {
        synchronized (tasks) {
            return tasks.size();
        }
    }

    public Result<T> submit(Taskable<T> task) {
        Result<T> result = new Result<T>();
        synchronized (tasks) {
            this.tasks.add(new Work<T>(result, task));
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static void test() throws InterruptedException {
        int count = 0;
        ReusableThread<Integer> rt = new ReusableThread();
        rt.start();

        Thread.sleep(10);

        System.out.println("Thread-"+ count +" starting");
        Result<Integer> result = rt.submit(JavaUtils::task);
        System.out.println("In main : " + rt.getTaskSize()); //This prints 1
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        test();
    }
}
```

and you should add Thread.sleep() to while(true) loop, If don't you will get 100% cpu soon

Comment: But this does not seems to be a synchronization issue though your things solves it.

Comment: The problem is 'thread-safety' - 'race condition', and synchronization  is a way to resolve it